# Why slides in this page doesn't work with the last version of Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

this site worked well with most of browsers... But with the last version of Google Chrome I can't see any image... Can someone help me?

http://www.bexnet.it/BExpresso/

Answer (score 0):

Declare a height on the wrapper and that will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Also:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.bexnet.it/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js

Comment: I've declared an height and i removed the link to the mousewheel pack, but it doesn't still work.

Answer (score 0):

Your slides list has overflow hidden and for some reason it's width is 0. Add width:100% to fix

```
.blueberry .slides {
   width: 100%;
}
```